# Print text with the highest number in adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been having trouble adding some features to my dashboard. My current formula is returning N/A (simple vloopup with MAX).

**My Goal:**

- A person who has been a client for the most amount of days is the
  favourite client
- If two or more clients have been a client for the    same amount of
  days, pick the one higher up on the column, or pick one randomly (as long as it's not an error)

**DATA:**

```
    A       B
1  DAYS   CLIENT
2   4      Josh
3   4      Sam
4   6      Aya
5   2      Zaptos
6   12     Goku
7   12     Gandalf
8   11     Tim
9
```

So the output should be Goku as he and Gandalf have been clients for the longest, but Goku is higher up in the column than Gandalf.

I would also be happy if the output was randomly selected between Goku and Gandalf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(MAX($A$2:$A$8),$A$2:$A$8,0))
```

This will return the first matching client - Goku in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:B,2,0)
```